# Why my Spring webflux application makes temp file on every request?

Tags: java, spring, nio, spring-webflux, bytebuffer

why does spring webflux (or java nio) makes multipartData DataBuffer tmp file?

in my case on macOS, files like `/private/var/folders/v6/vtrxqpbd4lb3pq8v_sbm10hc0000gn/T/nio-file-upload/nio-body-1-82f11dbe-61b3-4e5d-8c43-92e02aa38481.tmp` made on request and then deleted.

is it possible to improve performance with preventing disk write?

this is my code:

```java
public class FileHandler {
    public Mono<ServerResponse> postFile(ServerRequest req) {
        val file = req.multipartData()
                .map(map -> map.getFirst("file"))
                .ofType(FilePart.class);
        val buffer = file.flatMap(part -> part.content().next());
        val hash = buffer.map(d -> {
            try {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                md.update(d.asByteBuffer());
                return Base64Utils.encodeToString(md.digest());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // does not reach here!
                return "";
            }
        });
        val name = file.map(FilePart::filename);
        return ok().body(hash, String.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [multipart file support in Spring WebFlux is using the Synchronoss NIO Multipart library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart). The downside of that implementation is that it's not fully reactive and as a result it can create temporary files to not load the whole content in memory.

What makes you think that this behavior is a performance problem? Do you have a sample or benchmark results that show that this is an issue?

The Spring Framework team already worked on this and a fully reactive implementation will be available as the default in Spring Framework 5.2 (see [spring-framework#21659](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21659)).